# Appending to / removing elements from vector while iterating over said vector

Tags: vector, filter, iterator, rust, move-semantics

I have a vector `v` I want to iterate over, while executing a function on each element which

- modifies the element (could be done using `map()`)
- after that possibly removes the current element, depending on what was the result of the function (`filter()` -- but I do not want to call the function again, due to it modifying the state of the element)
- additionally might spawn new elements which should be appended to `v`:  This is *really* tricky, since I want the iteration to continue iterating over these freshly appended elements in the same loop which could, again, spawn new elements which could be appended and so on and so forth -- possibly never ending.

One very much simplified example is this one:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1,2,3];

    let mut i = 0;
    while i < v.len() {
        println!("{}", v[i]);

        // 1. modify element
        v[i] += 1;

        // look at result
        match v[i] % 3 {
            // 2a. remove element
            0 => {
                // no i increment since next element now has same index
                v.remove(i);
            },
            // 2b. append element
            1 => {
                let temp = v[i];
                v.push(temp+1);
                i += 1;
            },
            // 2c. do nothing
            _ => i += 1,
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Rather than manually using `while` I'd love to use iterators in some way or another. `filter_mut()` already accomplishes 1, 2a. (and 2c.) but 2b. I have no idea how to handle.

Due to appending possibly being recursive just holding a queue of newly appended elements does not suffice, at least a loop over such queues or similar would be needed -- but this, too, is not really "nice".

There are some similar questions out there but they seem not to completely cover what I want to do.

Comment: *some similar questions out there* — please link to them.

Comment: *I'd love to use iterators* —  you can't. TL;DR the duplicate, iterators contain a **reference** to the underlying slice. Adding / removing an item can cause the vector to reallocate, invalidating the reference. Safe Rust isn't allowed to have invalid references. Writing the plain loop and jumping around via indexes is the solution.